# Updating data with Ajax loading does not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, gif

I have an admin page which can insert, update and delete data. I want to display a simple loading gif while doing any of these operations. All of the 3 operations work perfectly, but when I try to make some Ajax with it, it stops working.

Below is my Ajax code. This code simply shows a `div` which has the loading gif within it, right after submitting the form, and if it's successfully accomplished, hides it again. That easy.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#loading").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Operations.php",
        dataType: "HTML",
        success: function() {
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Now, the `Operations.php`, that is executed by every form, contains the 3 database operations. It stores the name of the class sent by a `hidden` field, receives the value from the `button` of the submitted form and depending on its value, it instantiates the `ServiceDatabase` passing the class and perform one action.

```
$class = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "class");
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id");

@require_once "../../php/Connection.php";
@require_once "../../php/ServiceDatabase.php";
@require_once "../../php/" . $class . ".php";

$Operation = new ServiceDatabase($connection, new $class);

switch ($_REQUEST["submit"]) {
    case "insert":
        $Operation->setPostVariables();
        $Operation->insert();
        break;
    case "update":
        $Operation->setPostVariables();
        $Operation->update($id);
        break;
    case "delete":
        $Operation->delete($id);
        break;
}
```

And finally, just the form.

```
<form id="form" class="center-block" action="Operations.php" method="post">
    <h3>Alterar - <small><?php echo $class ?></small></h3>

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $class ?>" name="class"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="id"/>

    <?php echo $Table->generateAdminTables($id); ?>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-success btn-update">Atualizar</button>
</form>
```

What happens is that the database operation, in this case, the update, doesn't work, like if it is not reaching the `Operations.php` file.

Comment: I dont think you are inserting the data anywhere.

Comment: I don't want to insert anything, just execute the `update()` while my `div` with a loading GIF within is visible.

Comment: Might be `success: function()`. If i recall correctly you needed to specify two parameters in the function.

Comment: Actually 3 parameters. Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `$_REQUEST` doesn't work with Ajax. What a surprise.

My solution is: I created a new `hidden` in the forms to receive via jQuery the `value` of the clicked `button`:

```
btnValue = "";
$("#form button").click(function() {
    btnValue = $(this).attr("value");
});
```

Then right before the `$.ajax`, I set the `hidden` value:

```
$(this).find("#action").attr("value", btnValue);
```

In my `Operations.php`, a new `$_POST` value is received

```
$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "action");
```

And in the `switch` block, I just check `$action`

```
switch ($action) {
    case "insert": ...
    case "update": ...
    case "delete": ...
}
```

Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `POST` data which you get from the form.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Operations.php",
    method: "POST", // defaults to get
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data and send it
    dataType: "HTML",
    success: function() {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but it did not work. When I write the Ajax code, even if it returns a "success" message by `textStatus` parameter of the `success`, the `update()` method does not execute, but if I erase the Ajax, it works. It seems there is something blocking the execution.

Comment: Can you use your browsers debugger to see what is being sent as post variables in the two cases. 1) using ajax. 2) not using ajax?

Comment: I have never used this debugger, I don't understand anything yet. Can't say the difference. I don't understand why it happens, what is missing in there. I have another form that sends an email with Ajax and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I have not tested but it will work.

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#loading").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Operations.php",
        dataType: "HTML",
        success: function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
        },
        error: function (data) {
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            //A function to be called when the request finishes
            // (after success and error callbacks are executed).
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already solved my problem and soon I will mark my solution as the answer.